# AspNetCore Oidc authentication does not work correct with PathBase

Tags: asp.net-core

My application is running behind a gateway and has a middleware that handles setting the pathbase property of the context.

PathBase will be set to "/identity/";

Then using the following authentication setup in configure services will not work correct unless i explicit add the now commented out lines.

```
                    authentication.AddOpenIdConnect("AAD", "Azure Active Directory", options =>
                    {
                       // options.CorrelationCookie.Path = "/identity/aad-signin-oidc";
                       // options.NonceCookie.Path = "/identity/aad-signin-oidc";
                        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                        options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
                        options.CallbackPath = "/aad-signin-oidc";
                        options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
                        options.ClientId = appRegistration.SelectToken("$.appId").ToString();// "f98fa34a-2aa2-4ff4-b7bf-a7ef5ab1890b";
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                        options.Scope.Add("profile");
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = false
                        };
                        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                        options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (r) =>
                        {
                       //     r.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = r.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.Replace("identity//", "identity/");

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };
                    });
```

[image]

Comment: What if you set path base to "/identity"? The rules for merging slashes are different in a uri vs a file path.

Comment: Its my reverse proxy that sets the basepath in headers and I will try to update that to ignore the last slash - but what does specs say. Should it not always ends with slash? like is a empty basepath not also "/" ?

Comment: No, Path is expected to start with a slash so a trailing slash on PathBase is redundant.